Why is steaming food faster than boiling it?
I had for a long time been of the belief that steaming food (say broccoli) was faster than boiling it. That is, over a fixed period of time, the heat transferred from steam in a closed pot of boiling water would exceed the heat transferred by the boiling water if an object were surrounded by only one of the substances. This is supported by the wikipedia article Steaming which says:

Compared to full immersion in boiling water, steaming can be faster and more energy-efficient because it requires less water and takes advantage of the excellent thermodynamic heat transfer properties of steam.

Why is this the case? Shouldn't the temperature of the steam and water be the same (because both phases are, in a sealed container, to a good approximation, at equilibrium). What "excellent thermodynamic heat transfer properties of steam" do they refer to?

You are missing the obvious contribution of the latent heat of vaporisation

This would seem more appropriate to [cooking.se] where they do discuss the science of cooking as well as more practical and esoteric aspects.

"...more energy-efficient because it requires less water..." It takes less heat (and probably, on your puny stove-top, less time) to get the steamer up to cooking temperature than it takes to get a whole pot full of water up to the same temperature.

When you say "closed pot", do you mean a pressure cooker, or a pot with a loose lid being held in place by gravity alone?

Of course in a kitchen, steaming can be more energy-efficient for another reason: you can steam your beans over the top of boiling your potatoes (for example), with no more energy input, or at least very little

This is certainly an interesting question, but it may be based on a false premise.
Despite the claim by Wikipedia and many other online sources, it does not appear to be true that ambient-pressure steaming of food is a consistently faster cooking method than boiling it.
Cooking times seem more limited by thermal conductivity within the food item than the difference in surface heat transfer between boiling and steaming.
If we only count the time after the food item is placed in the boiling water or steam, then according to the (admittedly sparse) research literature, steaming is usually slower than boiling.
If, however,  we include the time taken to heat the water to boiling (as noted in @Solomon-Slow's comment), there is no question that steaming food is usually faster overall. It takes much less time to boil the smaller amount of water needed to make sufficient steam than to boil the large amount of water needed to cover food items. For example, it might only take 4 minutes to boil the 500 mL of water needed to steam a pot of potatoes, but almost 20 minutes to boil the 4 L of water needed to cover the potatoes. Similarly, boiling broccoli might take 3 minutes compared to 4 minutes for steaming, but this ignores the 4 minutes needed to heat the water for boiling which makes a total of 7 minutes for boiling from a cold start.
For more discussion of the relevant physics, see my question and answer: "Why is steaming food not faster than boiling it?".
Optimal cooking times for boiling versus steam from the research literature
Given that cooking times are important for food safety, I was surprised how hard it was to find cooking times in the research literature for boiling vs steaming . Below are cooking times (in minutes) that I found. The shorter of the steaming and boiling times are in boldface; differences $\leq 10$% are considered a tie.
$$
\begin{align}
&Vegetable&                            &\quad Boiling     &&Steam      &&Source                       \\
&\mathrm{Asparagus}&                   &\quad\mathbf{ 2.5}&&         6 &&\mathrm{DanowskaOziewicz2020}\\
&\mathrm{Beans\ (green)}&              &\quad\mathbf{15  }&&        17 &&\mathrm{Warthesen1984}       \\
&\mathrm{Broccoli}&                    &\quad\mathbf{ 3  }&&         4 &&\mathrm{Bongoni2014}         \\
&&                                     &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\
&&                                     &\quad\mathbf{ 7  }&&\mathbf{ 7}&&\mathrm{Rennie2010}          \\
&&                                     &\quad\mathbf{ 7.5}&&\mathbf{ 8}&&\mathrm{DanowskaOziewicz2020}\\
&&                                     &\quad         8   &&\mathbf{ 7}&&\mathrm{Warthesen1984}       \\
&&                                     &\quad\mathbf{ 8  }&&        13 &&\mathrm{Pellegrini2010}      \\
&&                                     &\quad\mathbf{10  }&&\mathbf{10}&&\mathrm{TorresdeCastro2020}  \\
&\mathrm{Blue\;Crab}&                  &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&         7 &&\mathrm{Hazard2010}          \\
&\mathrm{Brussels\ sprouts}&           &\quad\mathbf{10  }&&        17 &&\mathrm{Pellegrini2010}      \\
&\mathrm{Cabbage}&    \mathrm{shredded}&\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{Rennie2010}          \\
&                       &\mathrm{wedge}&\quad\mathbf{10  }&&\mathbf{10}&&\mathrm{Warthesen1984}       \\
&                   &\mathrm{quartered}&\quad\mathbf{48  }&&        58 &&\mathrm{Torgerson1933}       \\
&\mathrm{Cauliflower}& \mathrm{florets}&\quad         6   &&\mathbf{ 5}&&\mathrm{Warthesen1984}       \\
&           &\mathrm{ with 2.5 cm stem}&\quad\mathbf{10  }&&        13 &&\mathrm{Pellegrini2010}      \\
&\mathrm{Chard}&                       &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\
&\mathrm{Carrots}&      \mathrm{sliced}&\quad        10   &&\mathbf{ 7}&&\mathrm{Rennie2010}          \\
&           &\mathrm{2.5\;cm\;cylinder}&\quad\mathbf{ 8  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{TorresdeCastro2020}  \\
&       &\sim\mathrm{2.5\;cm\;cylinder}&\quad\mathbf{10  }&&\mathbf{10}&&\mathrm{Warthesen1984}       \\
&                 &\mathrm{2\;cm\;cube}&\quad\mathbf{12  }&&        15 &&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\
&               &\mathrm{2.5\;cm\;cube}&\quad\mathbf{30  }&&        35 &&\mathrm{Torgerson1933}       \\
&\mathrm{Corn\ (sweet)}&               &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&        20 &&\mathrm{Zhang2022}           \\
&\mathrm{Crayfish}&                    &\quad\mathbf{ 4  }&&\mathbf{ 4}&&\mathrm{Li2023}              \\
&\mathrm{Crown\ Daisy}&                &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\
&\mathrm{Fish\ Filets\ (Sea\ Bass)}&   &\quad\mathbf{10  }&&\mathbf{10}&&\mathrm{NievaEchevarría2017} \\
&\mathrm{Mallow}&                      &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\
&\mathrm{Noodles\ (wheat)}&            &\quad\mathbf{ 3.5}&&        15 &&\mathrm{Tian2020}            \\
&\mathrm{Pak\;Choi}&                   &\quad\mathbf{10  }&&        15 &&\mathrm{Chen2019}            \\
&\mathrm{Peas}&                        &\quad\mathbf{10  }&&         8 &&\mathrm{Warthesen1984}       \\
&\mathrm{Perilla\ Leaf}&               &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\
&\mathrm{Pork}            &\mathrm{Ham}&\quad\mathbf{27  }&&\mathbf{30}&&\mathrm{Jeon2013}            \\
&                     &\mathrm{Sausage}&\quad\mathbf{10  }&&        19 &&\mathrm{Prapasuwannakul2017} \\
&\mathrm{Potatoes}&\mathrm{2\,cm\;cube}&\quad\mathbf{20  }&&\mathbf{20}&&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\
&           &\mathrm{\sim2.5\,cm\;cube}&\quad\mathbf{20  }&&        32 &&\mathrm{Torgerson1933}       \\
&       &\mathrm{\sim6.5\,cm\;diameter}&\quad\mathbf{28  }&&        40 &&\mathrm{Warthesen1984}       \\
&\mathrm{Semolina}&                    &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{ElYamlahi2014}       \\
&\mathrm{Spinach}&                     &\quad\mathbf{ 4  }&&         9 &&\mathrm{Warthesen1984}       \\
&&                                     &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\                   
&&                                     &\quad\mathbf{ 8  }&&        10 &&\mathrm{Caparrotta2019}      \\                   
&\mathrm{Squid}&                       &\quad\mathbf{ 5  }&&\mathbf{ 5}&&\mathrm{Xiao2021}            \\
&\mathrm{Sweet\;Potato}&               &\quad\mathbf{20  }&&\mathbf{20}&&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\
&\mathrm{Zucchini}&                    &\quad         6   &&\mathbf{ 4}&&\mathrm{Warthesen1984}       \\
&&                                     &\quad\mathbf{10  }&&        12 &&\mathrm{TorresdeCastro2020}  \\
&&                                     &\quad\mathbf{12  }&&        15 &&\mathrm{Lee2018}             \\
\end{align}
$$
Links to Sources (Hovering over link shows full citation):
Bongoni2014,
Caparrotta2019,
Chen2019,
DanowskaOziewicz2020,
ElYamlahi2014,
Hazard2010,
Jeon2013,
Lee2018,
Li2023,
NievaEchevarría2017,
Pellegrini2010,
Prapasuwannakul2017,
Rennie2010,
Tian2020,
Torgerson1933, TorresDeCastro2020,
Xiao2021,
Warthesen1984,
Zhang2022.
The average cooking time used for steaming is a third longer than the average time for boiling.
Another way to compare steaming and boiling is to measure how fast a vegetable softens. As shown in the plot below, Buratti et al. (2020) found that the desired firmness was reached faster by boiling than steaming for cauliflowers, carrots, and sweet potatoes.

In addition to the data showing that steaming is usually slower than boiling, the often small differences between steaming and boiling times indicate that the limiting factor on cooking times is not the heat transfer from the water/steam through the surface of the food item, but the effective thermal conductivity within the food.
Heat transfer coefficients are not the whole story
The nice answer by @Testina is certainly correct about steam being able to transfer more heat per gram of water, but as @Sophie-Swett's comment noted, this doesn't mean that that rate of heat transfer into the food is faster.
It is true, as @Eric-Tower's useful comment noted, according to steam experts at tlv.com the convective heat transfer coefficient for steam ($h \approx 6000 – 15000 \,\mathrm{W/m^2/K}$) is much higher than that of boiling water ($h \approx 1000\,\mathrm{W/m^2/K}$). This does not, however, necessarily translate into a much greater overall heat transfer coefficient ($U$) into an object, which also depends on the length scale ($L$) and thermal conductivity ($\lambda$) of the object:
$$\frac{1}{U}\sim \frac{1}{h}+\frac{L}{\lambda}$$
In the examples given in the cited source, steam heating is only 17% faster than boiling water at heating a steel kettle, and adding just a 1 mm layer of glass to the outside of the kettle reduces steam's advantage to just 9%.
The thermal conductivity of food  is even less than glass and food items are typically thicker than 1 mm, so any theoretical advantage of steam heat penetrating into food may often be negligible in practice. For example, for a 3.5 cm radius spherical potato with thermal conductivity of $0.6\,\mathrm{W/m/K}$ we expect:
$$\begin{align}
U_{boiling}&\sim \left(\frac{1}{1000\,\mathrm{W/m^2/K}}+\frac{0.035\,\mathrm{m}}{0.6\,\mathrm{W/m/K}}\right)^{-1}=16.85\,\mathrm{W/m^2/K}\\
U_{steaming}&\sim \left(\frac{1}{100\,\mathrm{W/m^2/K}}+\frac{0.035\,\mathrm{m}}{0.6\,\mathrm{W/m/K}}\right)^{-1}=17.11\,\mathrm{W/m^2/K}
\end{align}$$
So the theoretical advantage of steaming over boiling for our potato is less than $2$%, but perhaps the more important point is that we expect cooking times for boiling and steaming to be very similar.  Even for smaller food items, the advantage of steam should be less than $10$%. The observed slight advantage of boiling over steaming is presumably due to minor effects which we haven't considered, e.g. liquid vs gas porosity of the food item, possibly lower effective temperature of the steam+air, ….
Nevertheless, "Introduction to thermal food processes by steam and hot water" did report that steam is more common than boiling for industrial food processing:

Because of its advantages, saturated steam is the most often utilized heating medium for commercial sterilization of packaged goods. When saturated vapor condenses on the container's surface, latent heat is transmitted to the food.


Because the heat transmission coefficient of condensing steam is larger than that of hot water, steam blanching takes less time than water blanching for sliced and small products. Larger products or parts of product, on the other hand, can be “overblanched” near the surface and “underblanched” at the center due to strong temperature gradients between the surface and the center of the product.

The advantage of steam in industrial processing, however, may have less to do with any better heat transmission than with the fact the steam is 3 orders of magnitude less dense than boiling water. It is easier to move steam than water, and easier to move product through steam than through water on a production line.
Human Factors Affecting Cooking Times

As emphasized by the well-known saying that "A watched pot never boils", waiting for water to boil can stretch out time in our minds, so it may also be more psychology than physics that makes us not notice that boiling water actually heats food faster than steam.

Steaming may also often be faster in part because of many people have different expectations for steamed and boiled food.
If you expect steamed vegetables to be firm and boiled vegetables to be soft, you would naturally use shorter times for steaming than boiling.
This might help explain the wide variations in recommended cooking times from different sources.
For example, Betty Crocker recommends longer steaming times than boiling times for most vegetables, this vegetable cooking cheat sheet usually recommends shorter steaming than boiling times, and this site is about evenly split.


Related Questions

If steam and water, both at 100 °C, were exposed to a person's skin for a small time interval, which would result in a more severe burn?
"Why do we "feel" steam at 100 °C as hotter than water at 100 °C?"


I'm glad somebody examined the basic premise. There are lots of reasonable sounding theoretical explanations here for why steaming might be faster, but the practical results show otherwise.

+1 I would like to add that the change in density between the two phases has to be considered: At 100°C, the density of steam is significantly lower than the density of water; while water has a density close to 1 g/cm³, steam has a density of around 0.0006 g/cm³, meaning steam is roughly 1,000 times less dense than liquid water at the same temperature. What ever additional heat due to heat of vaporization is diluted by a factor of 1000.

Comprehensive answer.

When you boil something, the food is sitting in hot water. The water at $100 \ ^\circ \text{C}$ touches the surface of the food and heats it up. Simple heat transfer—just conduction. But with steaming, things are a bit more interesting.
Steam is still at $100 \ ^\circ \text{C}$, but it’s packed with extra energy. Why? Because to turn water into steam, water absorbs a lot of heat (called the latent heat of vaporization). For water, this is about $2260 \ \text{J/g}$. So, each gram of steam carries a lot more energy than just hot water.
Now, when that steam hits the surface of your cooler broccoli, it condenses back into the water, dumping all that extra energy (the $2260 \ \text{J/g}$) right into the food.
Let’s break this down with some numbers:

Boiling water at $100 \ ^\circ \text{C}$ transfers heat to food just based on the temperature difference. It’s about $4.18 \ \text{J}/(\text{g} \ ^\circ\text{C})$ for water.

Steam, on the other hand, not only brings the same temperature heat ($100 \ ^\circ \text{C}$) but also releases $2260 \ \text{J/g}$ when it condenses on the food.


The Math:

Boiling: Let’s say you’ve got $100 \ \text{g}$ of water. If that heats something up by $1 \ ^\circ \text{C}$, you get:
$$
  Q_{\text{boiling}} = mc\Delta T = 100 \ \text{g} \times 4.18 \ \text{J}/(\text{g} \ ^\circ\text{C}) \times (1 \ ^\circ \text{C}) = 418 \ \text{J}.
$$

So, boiling water gives you $418 \ \text{J}$ to raise the temperature by $1 \ ^\circ \text{C}$.

Steaming: Now let’s look at $1 \ \text{g}$ of steam condensing on food. That steam delivers $2260 \ \text{J}$ just from condensing! Then, it turns back into water at $100 \ ^\circ \text{C}$, which can still transfer its normal heat:

$$
  Q_{\text{steam}} = 1 \ \text{g} \times 2260 \ \text{J/g} + 1 \ \text{g} \times 4.18 \ \text{J}/(\text{g} \ ^\circ\text{C}) \times (1 \ ^\circ \text{C}) = 2260 \ \text{J} + 4.18 \ \text{J} = 2264.18 \ \text{J}.
$$
So, $1 \ \text{g}$ of steam can transfer more than $5$ times the energy that $100 \ \text{g}$ of boiling water can just by condensing. That is significant.

Steam can easily go above 100 °C, so there's even more energy available there.

Do you have any justification for your implicit assumption that the amount of time it takes for 1 g of steam to condense during steaming is similar to the amount of time it takes for 100 g of water to be cooled by 1 °C during boiling? For all I know, in a typical situation, maybe the former takes 10 seconds and the latter takes 1 second.

@SophieSwett : For water this rate is 1-6 kJ/(s m^2 K) and for steam, this rate is 6-15 kJ/(s m^2 K).  So, other things not being wildly different (e.g., contact with boiling water on a tiny patch versus completely engulfed in steam), the rate of heat transfer is about 3-4 times faster for steam than water.

@Rad80 - In a cooking pot there is nothing at more than 100ºC to heat steam over that temperature. The only thing hotter may be the outer side of the base of the pot, which is in contact with the fire.

@SophieSwett It's more complex than can be covered by answering your query as asked. || As written Testina is correctly saying that the energy contents are identical. The 1 C drop for hot water is nominal - you could consider 0.1C or 10C. But, the steam condensation MUST release all the energy AT 100 C. If it doesn't it remains partially as steam.  || Eric provides two formulas (source not stated, alas) that claim transfer rates. These may be in the order of right. Or not. || If 100C steam comes in contact with material below 100C the contact boundary will remain AT 100C ...

... until the steam is wholly condensed. There is NO < 100C steam. This is unlike water where 100C water applied to a su 100C surface will cool as energy is transferred. New 100C water may well replace the surface water (by eg boiling agitation) but steam is substantially more "aggressive" than water. Presumably this is what is reflected in Eric's formulae.

@EricTowers Can you provide a link to material related to your heat transfer rate expressions. I'm interested in better understanding the subject. [[(73. ME(elec). Interested in everything technical :-) ]] || See my comments to Testina above. Comment on / agreement or disagreement with these is welcomed.

@RussellMcMahon : A resource is https://www.tlv.com/en-us/steam-info/steam-theory/steam-basics/overall-heat-transfer-coefficient  .  Happily, I note they have the same numbers I recalled...  :-)

You're absolutely right—how quickly heat transfers and the time it takes are really important when comparing steaming and boiling. Since steam condenses really quickly, it can usually transfer heat faster than boiling water, so it’s not a stretch to assume that these processes happen in similar time frames, which helps explain why steaming is more efficient for cooking food. But, to rigorously justify this, we would need to consider detailed experimental data or conduct rate-of-transfer calculations. @SophieSwett

Given that the energy source remains the same in either case, and we're really just figuring out how to transport that energy into the broccoli, does this answer rely on us not counting the added time needed to get a pot of (let's assume room temperature) water to become steam in the first place? This answer addresses why (existing) steam is faster than (existing) boiling water, but I suspect the same would not be true if both scenarios started from the same pot of room temperature water and only altered the elevation of the broccoli (i.e. either in or above the water)?

I agree with the conclusion and the reasons, but theres one thing that seems to be overlooked.  Wouldnt boiling water also lead to vapour condensing on the broccoli?  You lose surface area, since it's mostly in contact with liquid water, but the vapor bubbles should contact the broccoli while at a boil, so it wouldnt be pure conduction.  Obviously steaming still wins by a long shot because even condensation on the brocolli starts before all the water reaches 100 deg.

I'm confused by the math on the energy transfer from boiling water, since it doesn't use the temperature at all. I could apply the same logic and arrive at the same figure for the heat transfer from, say, 30 degree water instead of 100 degree.

@SamJaques I think theres a slight wording problem in their answer.  It mentions the energy to heat something up 1 deg, but that's really the energy released when the temperature of the water drops 1 degree.  The energy per degree (per mass) released by liquid water is approximately the same across all temperatures.

The previous answers explain the merits of steaming vs boiling at the same temperature.
But look also at the practicalities of the arrangements for cooking with steam and boiling water.
Most boiling operations done in a typical kitchen will allow the steam to flow out of the boiling vessel - which is a significant heat loss.
A typical steaming operation will be done in an enclosed vessel so as to expedite steam production and retention within the cooking process. This involves significantly less heat lost during cooking.
So for a cooker with equal power input to two elements, a pressure cooker on one and a saucepan + lid (with chimney) on the other, we will get more heat into the food item per unit time via steaming than with boiling. The more heat going into the food, the shorter the cooking time.

Naïvely, I would say that steam may penetrate the pores of broccoli easier than water, where the molecules are tied together (even if not in a rigid structure). In a small pore where a single molecule can pass, the water cannot flow due to the surface tension.
Thus, in water the broccoli is heated mainly on the surface, and the cooking inside is due to the heat conductance of broccoli. On the other hand, vapor molecules penetrate inside broccoli, heating it almost uniformly.
The energy of the latent heat of vaporisation, mentioned in the comments, goes precisely to break the bonds between the water molecules.
Heat capacity and latent heat vs. heat transfer/conductance
In response to the comments it is necessary to point out that high heat capacity of vapor does not explain fast cooking of broccoli. Indeed, if the heat supplied to the pot at a constant rate, we actually need longer time to create sufficient amount of steam - precisely because of the latent heat. In fact, when boiling foods one usually reduces heat when water starts boiling - precisely to avoid spending extra energy on creation of unnecessary steam.
Furthermore, heat capacity and latent heat explanation does not take into account that steaming is efficient for some foods, but not for others - it works well for broccoli, but not for meat, potatoes or eggs (although meat and potatoes can be efficiently cooked in a pressure cooker.)
The explanation is thus in how heat transfer occurs between the steam and the broccoli. Lest somebody is unhappy with my explanation formulated in a "childish" language, you are welcome to make the same argument in terms of percolation of a gas vs. that of a liquid. See also: Darcy's law: Correction for gases in fine media and  Knudsen diffusion.
Finally, regarding the water-tightness vs. air-tightness of broccoli - our everyday experience also teaches us that plants breath through their leaves surface, but do not take water through it.

I am sceptical.

I'm trying to imagine broccoli which is somehow water-tight but not air-tight.

@Beanluc think of how plants breath vs how they drink - it is pointless to pour water on the leaves.

I suppose the pressure involved in a steaming cooker also helps the penetration of steam molecules through a porous material.

@Trunk I assumed that we talk simply about cooking on steam - where the pressure is close to atmospheric. In case of a pressure cooker the situation is indeed very different.

@RogerV. That's got nothing at all to do with cooking. The only thing right about this answer is the latent heat of steam. It has nothing to do with penetration at all. The extra heat is delivered straight to the surface, just like as with immersion in water.

@Beanluc if you can support your claim by experimental evidence/curations, I am a taker. Otherwise, it is just as much of a guesswork as my answer - at least, I am honest about my naïveté.

@Beanluc for example: steaming works for broccoli, but not for meat, potatoes or eggs. Why? Also, as far as the heat capacity is concerned, evaporating water requires energy, that is heating for longer time - so vapor cooking couldn't be faster.... unless heat transfer/conductance between steam and broccoli us faster.

I added some broccoli and cauliflower data to my answer that may be helpful.

@DavidBailey yours is a good one, and I upvoted it. Though your angle is mostly empirical, without explaining the mechanism.
